# Is there a way to hide certain types of files in an Atom Project

Tags: java, atom-editor

I am new to Atom. I am programming in Java, and I was wondering if it was possible to hide the .java~ and .class files from the file viewer on the left side. They would obviously still be in the folder, but just hidden for simplicity's sake. Here is a photo of my file viewer currently.[image]

Comment: check this https://discuss.atom.io/t/left-tree-view-pane-how-to-hide-files/29622

Answer (score 0):

This view is provided by the Atom core package `tree-view`. If you search for it under Settings / Packages, and then go the package's settings, you will see two relevant options:

- "Hide Ignored Names" refers to the Core setting "Ignored Names", where you can specify file name patterns to be ignored.
- "Hide VCS Ignored Files" refers to the files ignored by a VCS, e.g. through `.gitignore` in a git repository.